# activemq oom after enabling stomp

Tags: java, out-of-memory, activemq-classic, stomp

After enabling STOMP protocol (before it was only default protocol enabled) on the Activemq server it started to fail with oom. I have only 1 client using STOMP. It can work for 1 week without fails or fail a day after a restart. Here is the config file:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker useJmx="true" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="cms-mq" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationInterceptors>
            <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
                <virtualDestinations>
                    <virtualTopic name="VirtualTopic.>" selectorAware="true"/>
                </virtualDestinations>
            </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        </destinationInterceptors>

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false">
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false">
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="4 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="4 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="auto" uri="auto+nio://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;auto.protocols=default,stomp"/>
        </transportConnectors>
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

        <plugins>
          ... security plugins config...
        </plugins>

    </broker>

    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

start args:

```
/usr/java/default/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx1G -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=false -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/logs/heapDumps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8162 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8162 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//conf/jmx.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//conf/jmx.access -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//conf:/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//../lib/ -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//conf -Dactivemq.data=/opt/apache-activemq-5.13.0//data -jar /opt/activemq/bin/activemq.jar start
```

UPD:
From Eclipse MemoryAnalizer:

```
Leak Suspects
247,036 instances of "org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage", loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0xc02e9470" occupy 811,943,360 (76.92%) bytes. 

81 instances of "org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.FilePendingMessageCursor", loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0xc02e9470" occupy 146,604,368 (13.89%) bytes.
```

UPD:
Before having OOM error there are several error in the log like the following:

```
| ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[cms-mq] Task-13707
| INFO  | The connection to 'null' is taking a long time to shutdown. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerService[cms-mq] Task-13738
```

Would appriciate any help in debugging it. 
Can provide additional info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I examined the client code (ruby stomp client) and it turned out that there was 'activemq.subscriptionName' sub header without 'client-id' connect header.  When you set 'activemq.subscriptionName' subscription header that means that you want your subscriber to be durable. But you should also set 'client-id' connect header because otherwise it is autogenerated. When 'client-id' header is not set we have a situation in which the broker can't identify the stomp client by it's client id when it reconnects. As a result there were a lot of Offline Durable Topic Subscribers and messages were piling up for every client-id => OOM error.

Answer (score 2):

One guess is that you are flooding the broker with messages from the producer over STOMP and eventually blowing the broker memory.  You have turned producer flow control off which can lead to this with even the default JMS client, and STOMP is even easier to get into this situation since there isn't by default an ack going back to the producer to allow for a flow control mechanism, you have to request a receipt on each send to get that.

To debug this you need to start examining your broker logs and the destination and usage stats via the console or other tool of your choosing to see what the state of the broker is.

Comment: I'll turn on producer flow control. Let's see if it helps

Comment: Turing on producer flow control only helps if you also modify the STOMP client to request receipts on send.

Comment: I managed to reproduce OOM by connecting and then disconnecting with the stopm client in loop. Heap size was growing till OOM. What it indicates?

Comment: That you should gather data and go ask the project for help on their users mailing list.